# android xml error parsing xml:not well formed

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I'm very new to XML and I'm just learning it for the case of android development. But the IDE built a series of TextViews and EditTexts and two of them are giving me a "xml error parsing xml:not well formed" error(textView1 and editText2) I have asked my peers and instructor but none are really too sure as to what is going wrong.
All help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView android:layout_weight="30" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2"android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:ems="10" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3"android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText3"android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:ems="10" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4"android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText4" android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:ems="10" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView5"android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText5"android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:ems="10" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView6"android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText6"android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent)"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="40">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="30">
    <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/analogClock1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is this line:

```
        android:layout_height="fill_parent)"
```

In your first inner-LinearLayout. 
You should take away the ')' of course.

For some reason, the Editor does not give you the correct line of the error. 
While using Eclipse, you should use Ctrl(/apple)+shift+F. It will auto-format your file. 
After doing this, the error was easily found.

ps. Use match_parent instead of fill_parent, fill_parent is deprecated.